# Ways to stop SQL query from displaying a table multiple times?

Tags: sql

In my script, I have a table displaying the results of a SQL query. However, I am using the results as a summary, but the SQL is making the page display the table as many times as there are results (rows) in the returning SQL that are allowed because of the Where clause. I.e. if there were 3 groups of people summarized, the table repeats the same information 3 times

Are there any common ways to address this issue? Thanks!

```
SELECT 
    Demographics.Name,
    Demographics.NDoc_Number,
    Demographics.PID_alphanumeric,
    Demographics.Company,
    Demographics.Company_Name,
    Demographics.Location,
    Demographics.Location_Name,
    Demographics.Team_CMT, 
    Demographics.Case_Manager,
    Demographics.Case_Manager_UID,
    Demographics.SiteName, 
    CareEpisodes.BGNDATE, 
    CareEpisodes.BRFA, 
    CareEpisodes.ENDDATE, 
    CareEpisodes.ERFA,
    OASIS_Improvement.BGNRPT,
    OASIS_Improvement.ENDRPT,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE OASIS_Improvement.O_I_@Request.MooNum~
        WHEN 'NA'
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END),0) AS numberImproveNA,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE OASIS_Stabilization.O_S_@Request.MooNum~
        WHEN 'NA'
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END),0) AS numberStabilizeNA,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE OASIS_Improvement.O_I_@Request.MooNum~
        WHEN 'NA'
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END),0) AS couldShowImprovement,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE OASIS_Stabilization.O_S_@Request.MooNum~
        WHEN 'NA'
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END),0) AS couldShowStabilization,
    ISNULL(COUNT(Demographics.Name),0) AS patientCount,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE OASIS_Improvement.O_I_@Request.MooNum~
        WHEN 1
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END),0) AS doShowImprovement,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE OASIS_Stabilization.O_S_@Request.MooNum~
        WHEN 1
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END),0) AS doShowStabilization

FROM 
    Demographics  
     INNER JOIN OASIS_Improvement  ON 
    Demographics.NDoc_Number = OASIS_Improvement.NDocNumber 
     INNER JOIN OASIS_Stabilization  ON 
    Demographics.NDoc_Number = OASIS_Stabilization.NDocNumber AND
        OASIS_Improvement.BGNRPT=OASIS_Stabilization.BGNRPT
     INNER JOIN CareEpisodes  ON 
    Demographics.NDoc_Number = CareEpisodes.NDocNumber AND
        OASIS_Improvement.BGNRPT=CareEpisodes.BGNRPT
WHERE
    (Demographics.Company IN (@SingleQuote.Request.companyInput~) OR '@Request.companyInput~' = '') AND
    (Demographics.Location IN (@SingleQuote.Request.locationInput~) OR '@Request.locationInput~' = '') AND
    (Demographics.Team_CMT IN (@SingleQuote.Request.teamInput~) OR '@Request.teamInput~' = '') AND
    (Demographics.Case_Manager_UID IN (@SingleQuote.Request.clinicianInput~) OR '@Request.clinicianInput~' = '') AND
    CareEpisodes.ERFA <> 6 AND
    (OASIS_Improvement.O_I_@Request.MooNum~ = 'NA' OR
    OASIS_Improvement.O_I_@Request.MooNum~ = 1 OR
    OASIS_Improvement.O_I_@Request.MooNum~ = 0) AND
    (OASIS_Stabilization.O_S_@Request.MooNum~ = 'NA' OR
    OASIS_Stabilization.O_S_@Request.MooNum~ = 0 OR
    OASIS_Stabilization.O_S_@Request.MooNum~ = 1) AND
    CareEpisodes.BGNDATE >= '@Request.FromDateInput~' AND
    CareEpisodes.ENDDATE <= '@Request.ThruDateInput~'
```

Comment: Please include an example of the SQL query that you're having this problem with.

Comment: Are you asking how to **not** join a 1-to-many relationship?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what that means. On the page I have a table with row summaries. I want the table to display itself only once. However, the table is displayed with the exact same information as many times as there are results allowed by the SQL Where clause.

Comment: I think he's asking for a `group by`... maybe?

Comment: BLSully, yes I think you're right! that sounds familiar.. I will try variations of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think about using a GROUP BY statement if you are trying to group the information. If you want to summarize the information try looking at the GROUP BY but WITH ROLLUP. ROLLUP will allow you to group and summarize information depending on the values you select in  your GROUP BY.

Comment: Actually, what got me is that I had tons of values in the Select statement that I wasn't using. As soon as I deleted them, problem solved.

Comment: Nice! Sometimes just taking a few hours and then going back over the basics does wonders to solving problems. I can't tell you how many times I get stumped on a problem and then return to realize that I was over-complicating the hell out of it and a simple, basic fix is what solves it.